# JUpyterLab Rstudio Installation and configuration

Tags: rstudio-server, jupyterhub, jupyter-lab

I was trying to Install Rstdio with JupyterHUb and it works fine. But when I am switching to JupYterLab and I am not able to launch the RStudio sessions. Anybody has a quick forx or working solution for the same.

Best

Comment: we have a very similar problem. The problem only comes up after opening several jupyter notebooks. have you ever managed to fix yours?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534702/ulimit-one-service-affects-another

Comment: we have found out what our problem was: in `/etc/rstudio/profiles` we needed to increase the value for max open processes for all users. RStudio documentation is suggesting that this should be a high-enough number. `max-processes = 800`
EDIT: documented here https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/r-sessions.html under clause 5.2.5.2.